# Удаление коммитов

Tags: git, github

Есть ли способ не удаляя проект, удалить коммит на `github` ?

Comment: какую именно информацию? скрыть сам коммит но при этом изменения должны остаться?

Comment: @papiroca я говорю про сам коммит

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Есть ли способ не удаляя проект, удалить коммит на github?

абсолютно точный по форме ответ — нет.

а «правильный» ответ будет звучать так:

1. [удалите этот коммит в своей локальной копии хранилища](https://githowto.com/ru/removing_commits_from_a_branch).
2. отправьте это изменение в общее хранилище на github, добавив опцию `-f` (`--force`):

   ```
   $ git push -f
   ```
3. известите других пользователей этого общего хранилища, чтобы они и в своих локальных копиях удалили этот коммит (если «успели» его получить).
4. будьте готовы к тому, что:

   1. из локальных хранилищ других пользователей этого общего хранилища данный коммит, если он ими уже получен, никуда не денется (без их активного вмешательства).
   2. этот коммит опять появится в переписанной вами истории общего хранилища, если хоть один из других пользователей этого общего хранилища «успел» получить этот коммит, и, не предприняв действий по его удалению из своего локального хранилища, выполнит команду `push`.

Answer (score 1):

Тут гитхаб говорит как это сделать

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/