# Как удалить коммиты после удаления ветки?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

Ситуация:
Есть ветка законченной фичи.
После merge в общую ветку develop, ветку фичи удаляю.

Но ее коммиты по прежнему видны в истории:
[image: дерево коммитов]

Как их можно удалить или скрыть?

Comment: Merge как раз и заключается в добавлении коммитов из одной ветки в другу.

Comment: Зачем их удалять-то, если они формируют текущую историю?

Comment: ветка это просто метка, она к коммитам имеет весьма опосрденованное отношение, поэтому её можно удалять. Коммиты удалять нельзя, даже если есть некоторые методы это сделать.

Comment: Смысл удаления в том, чтобы сохранить только итоговые результаты работы в 1 коммите, а не распылять их по нескольким. Так я понял методологию работы с веткой фичи по [GitFlow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)

Comment: Значит перед merge делайте rebase, и squash всех коммитов в один.

Comment: @Skif вы неправильно поняли GitFlow

Answer (score 1):

каждый коммит содержит в себе (как неотъемлемую часть) ссылку на «родительский» коммит (коммиты слияния содержат более одной ссылки на «родителей»). «родительский» коммит, в свою очередь, содержит ссылку на своего «родителя», и так далее. так и выстраивается *связная* история изменений.

если удалить какой-нибудь коммит, то нарушится «связь времён» — ведь его «потомок» не содержит в себе ссылки на «деда».

восстановить связность без переписывания истории невозможно. а если задумаете переписать, то будьте готовы к [подводным камням](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576).

Comment: Вопрос я поставил не совсем корректно.

Comment: Наверно, правильнее было бы так: - можно ли увидеть общую ветку develop

Comment: Можно ли увидеть общую ветку develop - без вливаемых в нее веток фич? Чтобы из ветки фичи был виден только merge-коммит с финальным результатом.

Comment: в git ветка — всего лишь плавающий **указатель** на коммит, а не **набор** коммитов, как, например, в svn или mercurial. т.е. ваш **новый** вопрос сводится к переписыванию истории. на него ответ — да, это возможно. а *как* — многократно изложено (в том числе и на этом сайте) — например, с помощью rebase.