# Как удалить коммиты после удаления ветки (ветка не сливалась ни с чем)?

Tags: git, gitlab

Была ветка, которую нужно было удалить. Там было несколько коммитов больших.
Я, по незнанию, удалил эту ветку, но размер репозитория в байтах не уменьшился, тогда-то и смекнул я, что потерпел фиаско.
Теперь надо как-то удалить эти данные.
Проблема в том, что я эту ветку ни с чем не сливал. Т.е. она была сама по себе, потом выяснилось, что человек, запушивший ее, сильно накосячил.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить коммиты после удаления ветки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577971/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @Эникейщик неужели вы думаете, что я не увидел этого вопроса и задал свой? Тот вопрос похож, но в корне отличается по смыслу (уточнение в скобках).

Comment: совершенно верно, именно так и думаю.

Comment: Если коммитов не видно в дереве, значит все нормально удалили. Если вопрос именно в уменьшение размера репозитория, то стоит задавать вопрос про это) Можно принудительно сборку мусора запустить, см. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116778/

Answer (score 1):

При стандартных настройках удаление мусорных коммитов происходит при следующей переиндексации репозитория по прошествии двух недель от удаления.

Переиндексация выполняется автоматически при каждом `push`.

Запустить удаление мусорных коммитов можно вручную командой `git gc`, указав нужные параметры.

Под мусорными понимаются коммиты, на которые не ссылается ни одна ветка, ни одна метка и ни один не мусорный коммит не является его потомком.

Мусорные коммиты образуются не только при удалении ветки, но и при любых изменениях истории, таких как `rebase` и `commit --amend`