# Git откат веток на сервере

Tags: git

Подскажите пожалуйста. Создали на локальном репозетории 2 каторжные в конечном счете оказались не работоспособными - запушили его на удаленный репозеторий. Теперь хотелось бы откатить на 2 комита назад на локаальном и н сервере и продолжиь работать как "не в чем не бывало" - но нет , откатил на 2 комита назад методом git reset --hard HEAD~1 - но при git push- сервер отвечает , что не может залить данный комит т к  на сервер уже есть какие то новые изменения (т.е он говорит про те коммиты катрые мы как бы откатили )

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576

Comment: Я разобрался, всем нужен нужен ответ вот он : Воспользовался командой git push -f : и помогло то есть это команда отменяет последний ПУЛЛ - удаленный и локальный репозеторий удачно "синхронизировались" и я удачно продолжил работу . как всегда всем огромное спасибо http://tonyganch.com/git/reset/