# Как удалить последний, не локальный, коммит на гите?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Банально совершил ошибку когда писал коммит. Перфекционит внутри меня просит о помощи.
Нашел инструкцию с применением:

> git hist

Но, из за того что я пользуюсь git bash'eм на десятке, у меня не работает данная команда
 [image: ГитБаш]

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `git commit --amend -s; git push -f origin`, например. Но в публичных репозиториях так делать не надо. Ошибка? В релизную ветку пошла? Ну всё, забей. Просто подумай, что такое non-fastforward push.

Comment: `git hist` здесь — это всего лишь уточнённый алиас к `git log`. Можете использовать `git log` вместо него с тем же успехом. От терминала и ОС это не зависит

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576

Comment: Отметил дубликатом к аналогичному вопросу. Если понадобятся уточнения — задавайте там в комментариях **к ответу**, я обязательно отвечу.