# Как отменить смерженые ветки?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Я смержил локальную ветку(в которой вел разработку) в ветку мастера и запушил её, позже выяснилось что необходимо откатить изменения т.к. нашлась ошибка в логике моего кода, из-за чего мне нужно откатить ветку назад.Как это сделать? Понятно что можно создать комит отменяющий баг, но хотелось бы узнать как откатить ветку целиком,при том что в ветку мастер постоянно приливают множество веток.

Comment: Ты можешь локальную ветку сбросить до нужного коммита (mixed reset) далее, просишь коллег чтобы они не пушили - и делаешь force push. Твоя локальная копия заменит ветку в репозитории - коллеги заберут эти изменения и продолжат работу. Если в мастер уже что-то замёрджили - то просишь коллег влить ветки снова после твоих действий.

Comment: @SultanovShamil спасибо в похожей ситуации помог твой комментарии. Мне кажется, стоит его вынести в ответы

Answer (score 2):

1. в программе *git* (в отличие от многих других систем контроля версий) ветка — это **не** «набор изменений» (*коммитов*), а всего лишь **указатель** на одно конкретное изменение (*коммит*).
2. каждое изменение «намертво привязано» к предыдущему (в случае слияния — более чем к одному) изменению — в него включена хэш-сумма «предка».
3. такой набор связанных изменений называется *историей изменений*.
4. каждая копия (*клон*) хранилища (*репозитория*) содержит всю эту историю изменений (да, её можно «урезать», но это особый случай).

и если вы хотите, чтобы какого-то изменения (или ряда изменений) «вообще не было в истории», эту самую историю надо **переписать**. причём не только в вашей локальной копии и в той копии хранилища, которую вы используете совместно с другими разработчиками, но и [у **каждого разработчика** в его локальной копии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576).

поэтому наиболее простым (в организационном плане) вариантом будет именно «откат» (*revert*) нежелательных изменений.

можно откатить их «по одному», перечислив хэш-суммы изменений:

```
$ git revert хэш1 хэш2 ...
```

а можно откатить и то «изменение слияния» (*merge commit*), которое создалось при «вливании» ваших изменений. если выполнялось слияние только двух ветвей разработки (как в описанном вами случае), то:

```
$ git revert -m 1 хэш-изменения-слияния
```

---

чтобы впоследствие всё-таки применить эти изменения, надо будет откатить уже этот «откат»:

```
$ git revert хэш-изменения-с-откатом
```