# Перенос коммитов из одной ветки в середину другой

Tags: git, git-branch

Как можно перенести коммиты из одной ветки в ветку master, но вставить перед другими коммитами, а не в конец?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хм, а для чего нужно такое странное действие?

Comment: @AlexChermenin наколоть кого-то, что вовремя всё сделал %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский наколоть всех, развалив репозиторий)

Comment: автору вопроса: это называется «переписать историю». если вы не единственный пользователь хранилища, сие действо связано с проблемами. подробнее: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751168/178576) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576)

Comment: Перезапись истории мне не страшна, т.к. в удалённый репозиторий эти изменения ещё не запушены (последний коммит - C1).

Comment: Как насчет мержа а потом reset soft?

Comment: git cherry-pick, затем rebase. мне задача не нравится: толи локально создали ветку (молодец) и тут же рядом хреначили в мастер а потом одну ветку решили влить задним числом, толи было пять веток, четыре уже вмёрджили в мастер, а пятую вмёрдживают задним числом. Как ни крути задача так себе. Реализации не менее гиморные.

Comment: @AK, наоборот, это cherry-pick во время rebase с последующим возможным разрешением конфликтов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-хорошему, это классический `git rebase`, только совершаемый в нетипичную сторону:

```
git rebase feature master
```

Это, буквально, перенести историю `master` на историю `feature` (обычно делают наоборот) от их ближайшего общего основания (`C1`).

Имейте в виду, что коммиты `C2` и `C3` при этом изменятся.