# Сделал push не в ту ветку

Tags: git

Есть две ветки A и Б. Работал в ветке А, сделал коммит, и запушил случайно в другую.

Как мне отменить пуш? И изменения запушить в ветку А?

Answer (score 2):

1. лучше больше так не делайте. для этого стоит «забыть» про дополнительные аргументы команды `push` (см. ниже).
2. так как вам надо перезаписать историю в совместно используемом хранилище, [будьте готовы к возникающим при этом трудностям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576).
3. переназначить указатель `имя-ветки` (в вопросе — `Б`) в удалённом хранилище можно разными путями:

   1. если вам известен [хэш коммита, на который надо переставить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40580976/4827341), то:

      ```
      $ git push --force имя-хранилища хэш:имя-ветки
      ```
   2. если вы ещё не выполняли команд `pull/fetch`, то ваш локальный указатель `имя-ветки` (в вопросе — `Б`) всё ещё ссылается на нужный коммит. потому можно сделать и так:

      ```
      $ git checkout имя-ветки
      $ git push --force имя-хранилища имя-ветки
      ```

> Как изменения запушить в ветку А?

точно так же, как вы их «запушили в ветку Б», но «в ветку А»:

```
$ git checkout А
$ git push имя-хранилища А
```

---

ну а на будущее — [свяжите локальные указатели с удалёнными](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/track-remote-upstream-branch):

1. сразу после клонирования хранилища, содержащего несколько указателей (т.е., «веток»), при переключении (`checkout`) на указатель, ещё не определённый в вашей локальной копии хранилища, но определённый в удалённом хранилище, связывание происходит автоматически:

   ```
   $ git checkout имя
   Branch имя set up to track remote branch имя from origin.
   ...
   ```
2. если создали локальный указатель, не существующий пока в удалённом хранилище, то отправляйте его туда, не забыв про опцию `-u` (`--set-upstream`). указать её достаточно только один раз — при первой отправке:

   ```
   $ git push -u имя
   ...
   Branch имя set up to track remote branch имя from origin.
   ```
3. если забыли про `-u` при отправке, не страшно, можно связать и позже:

   ```
   $ git branch -u origin/имя
   Branch имя set up to track remote branch имя from origin.
   ```
4. посмотреть текущие привязки указателей можно командой `remote`:

   ```
   $ git remote show имя-хранилища
   * remote origin
     Fetch URL: ссылка
     Push  URL: ссылка
     HEAD branch: master
     Remote branches:
       master    tracked
       newbranch tracked
     Local branches configured for 'git pull':
       master    merges with remote master
       newbranch merges with remote newbranch
     Local refs configured for 'git push':
       master    pushes to master    (up to date)
       newbranch pushes to newbranch (up to date)
       somesome pushes to somesome (up to date)
   ```
5. теперь, когда локальный указатель связан с удалённым, отправить изменения можно простой командой `push`, без всяких там дополнительных аргументов:

   ```
   $ git push
   ```

   главное, что «промазать» при этом уже не получится.