# Отменить rebase

Tags: git

Есть две ветки (1 и 2). Хотел все коммиты из первой ветки перенести во вторую. А первую оставить не тронутой.

Перешел на вторую ветку. Сделал

```
git rebase 1
```

Запушил.

Обнаружил, что в первую ветку залились изменения со второй, а вторая не изменилась. Вот результат комманды git reflog

```
$ git reflog
1759017 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 1e8320... to Branch-1
1e83206 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): Branch-1
1759017 HEAD@{2}: rebase: checkout Branch-1
dd01ab8 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from Branch-1 to Branch-2
...
```

Как теперь мне откатить все назад и сделать правильно?

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/841831/178576

Comment: свяжите уже наконец ветки. и выполняйте просто `git push` без других аргументов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте ввести

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: Это может прервать идущий ребейз, но не отменить завершившийся.

Answer (score 1):

Найдите в reflog'е первой ветки состояние до rebase и выполните reset на тот коммит.