# Как сделать полную копию одной ветки в другую git?

Tags: git, github

Такая ситуация:
Есть ветка **продакшена**
Есть ветка **редизайна**
Есть ветка **мастер**а
Я работаю в ветке **редизайна** и по мере выполнение работы мерджу ее с **продом** - проблем нет
Сейчас заказчик решил что мерджить нужно в **мастер** - там дев сервер, там все изменения проверяются и потом заливаются на прод - все логично.
Проблема в том, что мастер это какая-то очень старая версия проекта, там куча всего лишнего и ненужного, ну и наоборот, там нет многого что щас есть на проде
Я пробую мерджить свою ветку **редизайна** в ветку **мастера**, фикшу конфилкты и все ок, но в мастере получается старючая версия проекта + мои изменения. Мне же нужно перетереть все начисто, то есть все мои файлы нужно полностью перенести на мастер, сам мастер не должен оставить после себя никаких файлов. Как это можно сделать подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Если вы в своей ветке добавили в коммит удаление старых файлов, то при слиянии в мастер, там эти файлы тоже удаляются.

Comment: Я ветвился от прода - ветка релизайна. Прод ветвился от мастера(поидее) после чего в мастере ничего не делалось, а в проде шла работа. Так вот я щас хочу слить ветку релизайна с веткой мастера, сливаю, получаю ошибки - смотрю в код, а там много кода с мастера, но этого кода уже нет не в проде не в ветки редизайна

Comment: создаете новую ветку old_master от мастера, сам мастер передвигаете на свою новую ветку. (git branch -f master <new-tip-commit>). если старый мастер ну совсем не нужен - удалите old_master. Но я бы оставил. Мало чего

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем понял. Мне нужно из ветки редизайна(впрочем можно и из продашкена, не суть важно) залить все в ветку мастера, но залить не просто смерджить, а залить так что бы в мастере получилась не объеденная ветка масте+редизайн, а что бы в мастере ничего не осталась от мастера и там было все идентично ветке продакшена

Comment: вот именно это похоже и будет. Ветка в гите это не что то хитрое и особое - это просто указатель на коммит.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть я делаю ветку old_master на всякий случай. После чего я переключаюсь в ветку редизайна.  И делаю git branch -f master redesigne? Или git branch -f master 19054388 (id cкоммита)?

Comment: имя ветки указывает на коммит. Поэтому, если redesigne в данный момент на 19054388, результат будет идентичный. `-f` нужен, что бы принудительно передвинуть ветку на указанный коммит

Answer (score -1):

если не важно, что будет в истории данного указателя (ветки и метки в программе *git* — это указатели), то можно просто перезаписать все файлы:

1. переключаетесь на указатель, который надо переделать:

   ```
   $ git checkout указатель1
   ```
2. удаляете все файлы и каталоги кроме каталога `.git`:

   ```
   $ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
   ```
3. распаковываете файлы, взяв их по нужному вам указателю:

   ```
   $ git archive указатель2 | tar -x
   ```
4. добавляете в индекс всё содержимое текущего каталога:

   ```
   $ git add .
   ```
5. делаете коммит:

   ```
   $ git commit
   ```

---

если же важно, чтобы история коммитов, доступных по указателю1, в точности соответствовала доступным по указателю2, то можно переименовать указатель1 и создать заново из указателя2:

1. переименовать указатель1 в другое_имя:

   ```
   $ git branch -m указатель1 другое_имя
   ```
2. переключиться на указатель2:

   ```
   $ git checkout указатель2
   ```
3. создать заново указатель1:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b указатель1
   ```
4. так как вы упомянули о совместной разработке, то теперь ещё потребуется перезаписать историю, доступную по указателю1 в общем хранилище (допустим, `origin`):

   ```
   $ git push -f -u origin указатель1
   ```

   как и при любом переписывании истории в совместно используемом хранилище, будьте готовы к дополнительным организационным действиям (см. пункты 3 и 4 из [другого моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576)).

Comment: Где-то лишнее движение -- можно вместо пары команд использовать _git checkout -b newbr oldbr_.