# Как переместить ветку на следующий коммит?

Tags: git

```
       c2-c4
c0-c1<
      c3-c5-c6
```

У меня ветка `main` находится на `c1`. Её нужно переместить на коммит `с6`. Как это сделать?

Comment: С каких пор ветку по коммитам "перемещают"? Опишите от А до Я что нужно сделать

Comment: Возможно из-за нехватки знаний я неправильно объяснил суть задания, но ответ от @Komdosh мне помог. Как правильно переформулировать вопрос не знаю. Если вы сможете с помощью этого ответа задать правильно вопрос - буду рад.

Comment: @InDevX, ровно с тех пор, как была написана программа git. в ней «ветка» («branch») и «метка» («tag») — это всего лишь указатели на коммит. // а вопрос отлично сформуилирован. ну, конечно, спрашивается в нём о самом базовом и элементарном, но у нас тут не клуб знатоков, а база знаний.

Comment: git merge c6 не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ресетнуть

```
git reset c6
```

где `c6` это хэш коммита. Если надо запушить результат, то при выполнении операции `reset` лучше использовать `git push origin --force`

[Замечание по поводу `push --force`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572872/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/572907#572907)

Comment: по поводу «push --force» в совместно используемое хранилище, думаю, лучше всё-таки делать оговорку о возможных проблемах. я в таком случае, чтоб не переписывать, просто ссылаюсь на свой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572907/178576), ну а вы можете сослаться и на любое другое описане «подводных камней».

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поздно, чем никогда ;)

Передвинуть указатель ветки `main` на коммит `c6`:

```sh
git branch -f main c6
```

> -f нужен т.к. `main` cуществует

Где находиться `HEAD` неизвестно, поэтому, на всякий случай, его можно передвинуть туда же:

```sh
git checkout c6
```

При этом, или уже, у вас состояние `detached HEAD` (отделенный HEAD)

> Это когда HEAD не указывает на указетель ветки, хотя они могут быть на одном коммите.
> При создании новых коммитов, `HEAD` перемещается на новый коммит, а `main` нет.

Что бы вернуть `HEAD` на `main` выполните следующую команду:

```sh
git checkout main
```

Или, не важно где сейчас находяться `main` и `HEAD`, возможно на разных коммитах, вы можете передвинуть `main` на `с6`, а `HEAD` на `main` одной командой:

```sh
git checkout -B main с6
```