# Как почистить историю коммитов в удаленном репозитории GitLab

Tags: gitlab

Из локального репозитория я удалил но на удаленном они остались, 2 коммита DinamicWeb

[image]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление коммитов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572872/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)